# Elastic search NOT boolean opeation with AND and OR

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I want to include and exclude the expertise using AND and OR ,Include with AND and OR operation working fine.But when using exclude expertise with AND and OR ,returns the same result count as 3. I am using elastic search version 1.4. Help me to fix this issue. Thanks in advance.

Below is my code OR operation with NOT

```
{
  "query_string": {
    "query": "et_tax:\"Commercial\" et_tax: \"Technology, Media & Telecoms\" AND ( -et_tax:\"Hotel,Leisure & Hospitality\" OR  -et_tax:\"Mergers & Acquisitions\")"
  }
}
```

AND operation with NOT

```
{
  "query_string": {
    "query": "et_tax:\"Commercial\" et_tax: \"Technology, Media & Telecoms\" AND  -et_tax:\"Hotel,Leisure & Hospitality\" AND  -et_tax:\"Mergers & Acquisitions\""
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer for my question for AND operation

AND NOT(et_tax:\"Hotel,Leisure & Hospitality\" AND  et_tax:\"Mergers & Acquisitions\")

For OR operation

AND NOT(et_tax:\"Hotel,Leisure & Hospitality\" OR et_tax:\"Mergers & Acquisitions\")